# Odd windows problem in the middle of poetry install for ansible-lint

Tags: python-poetry

I'm trying to add ansible-lint to poetry on Linux machine with Python 3.10.

I can't understand output:

```
poetry add ansible-lint
Using version ^6.14.2 for ansible-lint

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.2s)

  SolverProblemError

  The current project's Python requirement (>=3.10) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
    - will-not-work-on-windows-try-from-wsl-instead requires Python >=3.11,<4.0, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.10,<3.11 || >=4.0
  
  Because no versions of ansible-lint match >6.14.2,<7.0.0
   and ansible-lint (6.14.2) depends on will-not-work-on-windows-try-from-wsl-instead (*), ansible-lint (>=6.14.2,<7.0.0) requires will-not-work-on-windows-try-from-wsl-instead (*).
  Because will-not-work-on-windows-try-from-wsl-instead (0.1.0) requires Python >=3.11,<4.0
   and no versions of will-not-work-on-windows-try-from-wsl-instead match !=0.1.0, will-not-work-on-windows-try-from-wsl-instead is forbidden.
  Thus, ansible-lint is forbidden.
  So, because ansible-lean depends on ansible-lint (^6.14.2), version solving failed.
```

My pyproject snippet:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
ansible-core = "^2.14.3"
molecule = "^4.0.4"
black = "^23.1.0"
yamllint = "^1.29.0"
pytest = "^7.2.2"
pytest-testinfra = "^7.0.0"
```

What I've done wrong to get this message? Why there is windows in packages if I'm running linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ansible-lint` cannot be installed on Windows. See https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/discussions/2820

Add this to the `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` section in your `pyproject.toml` (adopt the version by your needs):

```
ansible-lint = { version = "^6.9.0", markers = "platform_system != 'Windows'" }
```

Run `poetry lock --no-update` and `poetry install` afterwards.

With this marker `ansible-lint` will be installed on Non Windows platforms, but will be skipped on Windows.

> Why there is windows in packages if I'm running linux?

Because Poetry locks the dependencies universal. It doesn't care about your current platform, nor your current Python Version.