# How to specify that a Poetry project is only installable on a specific platform?

Tags: cross-platform, python-poetry

I've run into a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75733049/96588) because Poetry tries to create a cross-platform lock file. But in my case the system will only ever be deployed on a single platform, so I want to tell Poetry to ignore all other platforms when resolving packages. Is this possible? Right now I have to set `markers = "platform_system == 'Linux'"` per package, and that's a chore.